# Remove all whitespace between bbcode

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I'm trying to remove all whitespaces between:

```
[code/][code]
```

For example:

```
[code]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask[/code]


[code]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask[/code]
lorem ipsum
[code]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask[/code]
```

I want to get:

```
[code]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask[/code]
[code]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask[/code]
lorem ipsum
[code]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask[/code]
```

My code:

```
$string = preg_replace('@\[code\]\[(s+)\]\[\/code\]@si', '', $string);
```

Comment: Its more about line breaks, not white-space. And your regex look between `code` tags, but your result is manipulated outside the tags.

Comment: I guess you want to remove line breaks (`\n`)

Comment: @modsfabio exactly

Comment: Use `preg_replace('~\[/code]\K\s*(?=\[code])~', '', $string);`

Answer (score 0):

Do you just mean spaces or all whitespace?

For just spaces, use str_replace:

```
$string = str_replace(' ', '', $string);
```

For all whitespace, use preg_replace:

```
$string = preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $string);
```

Comment: I just want remove whitespace BETWEEN [code/][code]

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this, using a regex and preg_replace():

```
$text = preg_replace('/\[(.*?)\]\s*\[/', '[\1][', $text);
```

Comment: How to limit it to only [code] tag?
$template = preg_replace('@\[(.*?)\]\s*\[@', '[code][', $template);